# Pandas failing with empty dataframe after upgrading pandas to 1.03 is it a bug or a feature? (TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I'm a bit perplexed that some of the neat features of pandas (dealing with empty dataframes in this example) are no longer supported, or is there a deeper reason for removing those. Here is a working toy example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1]})
mask = (df.a > 0) & df.apply(lambda row: row.a > 0, axis=1)]
print(df[mask])
```

✅ works fine

```
>   a
> 0 1
```

However 3 letter change fails:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1]})[:0]
mask = (df.a > 0) & df.apply(lambda row: row.a > 0, axis=1)
```

❌`TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [int64] array and scalar of type [float]`

This has not been an issue in earlier pandas 2.5

As there is only one column here, changing types won't help. The issue is of course in part due to panda returning dataframe itself when f(any) function is applied to an empty df.

*Comment: This example is quite silly, as both filters are doing the same thing, but I'm not aware of a good way of applying complicated filters (that have logic across multiple columns) other than via the **lambda** functions.*

Comment: what is the meaning of "df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1]})[:0]"? It creats an empty dataframe

Comment: In relation to your comment, `df[(df.a > 1) & (df.b > 2) & (df.c > 3)]` is a way to have multiple Boolean conditions. See [Pandas: Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney the simplest example that can't be written your way `row.b in row.a`

Comment: @PeiLi not sure what ar you asking. if you asking 'why do we need an empty df? then if we have a code that filters rows out than it very often happens that the result is an empty dataframe (especially with groupby) and the new pandas just breaks(!), when it wasn't before. If you are asking "why was it such a complicated definition" then I would say its not just an empty df, it's a dataframe with named columns and types (int). Also, I wanted to take code that runs and modify it ever so slightly so it wouldn't run.